# Hiding icons from the Ubuntu Dock

Tags: ubuntu-dock

[image: 1]

I wonder how can I hide the icons on the right in Ubuntu 22.04.1.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings -> *Appearance* -> *Configure Dock Behavior* and there are options there to show or hide volumes/rubbish bin.

[image]