# I want one single icon for "Files" (Nautilus) in dock

Tags: nautilus, dock

Is there a way to achieve this?
The problem: I use multiple smb shares, plus sometimes usb devices and sd cards. That makes a lot of entries in dock. I wouldn't mind that really, but that way I'm not able to cycle through all open Nautilus windows anymore (via ALT + ^)
Is this behavior meant to be some progress in usability, or is it due to some technical limitation?
Observed on 22.04 and Wayland.

Comment: Not files icons device icons.  This question addresses hiding device icons. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425379/hiding-icons-from-the-ubuntu-dock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comment/hint to "Hiding icons from the Ubuntu Dock"! That's exactly how I want it:
In "Files" I open a local directory.
In another window I open a smb share.
Both are listed under the same dock icon, and I can toggle between them.